# ActiveSupport::Duration incorrectly calculates interval?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I have a very strange feeling that I am getting incorrect duration calculated by ActiveSupport::Duration. Here is the essence of the code I have

```
require 'time'
require 'active_support/duration'
require 'active_support/gem_version'
a = Time.parse('2044-11-18 01:00:00 -0600')
b = Time.parse('2045-03-05 04:00:00 -0600')
ActiveSupport::Duration.build(b - a).inspect
ActiveSupport.gem_version
```

And here is what I get

```
[30] pry(main)> require 'time'
=> false
[31] pry(main)> require 'active_support/duration'
=> false
[32] pry(main)> require 'active_support/gem_version'
=> false
[33] pry(main)> a = Time.parse('2044-11-18 01:00:00 -0600')
=> 2044-11-18 01:00:00 -0600
[34] pry(main)> b = Time.parse('2045-03-05 04:00:00 -0600')
=> 2045-03-05 04:00:00 -0600
[35] pry(main)> ActiveSupport::Duration.build(b - a).inspect
=> "3 months, 2 weeks, 1 day, 19 hours, 32 minutes, and 42.0 seconds"
[36] pry(main)> ActiveSupport.gem_version
=> Gem::Version.new("6.0.1")
```

I cross-checked the result with PostgreSQL

```
select justify_interval('2045-03-05 04:00:00 -0600'::timestamp - '2044-11-18 01:00:00 -0600'::timestamp)
```

and got `3 mons 17 days 03:00:00` (or 107 days and 3 hours). Also there is a [web site that gives](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/timezoneduration.html?d1=18&m1=11&y1=2044&d2=5&m2=3&y2=2045&h1=1&i1=0&s1=0&h2=4&i2=0&s2=0) result consistent with PostgreSQL (although web page says 107 days are 3 months and **15** days).

Am I missing something? Where minutes and seconds are coming from? Is there a better interval calculator for Ruby/Rails?

**Update**
`distance_of_time_in_words` returns 4 months!

**Update 2**
I ended up with slightly modified Wizard's solution wrapped up to produce text

```
  def nice_duration(seconds)
    parts = duration_in_whms(seconds)
    out = []
    I18n.with_options(scope: 'datetime.distance_in_words') do |locale|
      out.push locale.t(:x_days, count: parts[:days]) if parts.key?(:days)
      out.push locale.t(:x_hours, count: parts[:hours]) if parts.key?(:hours)
      out.push locale.t(:x_minutes, count: parts[:minutes]) if parts.key?(:minutes)
    end
    out.join ' '
  end

  private

  def duration_in_whms(seconds)
    parts_and_seconds_in_part = {:days => 86400, :hours => 3600, :minutes => 60}
    result = {}
    remainder = seconds
    parts_and_seconds_in_part.each do |k, v|
      out = (remainder / v).to_i
      result[k] = out if out.positive?
      remainder -= out * v
    end
    result.merge(seconds: remainder)
  end
```

Apparently localization from Action View does not have hours without *about*. So I also had to add corresponding translation into my locales

```
en:
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      x_hours:
        one:   "1 hour"
        other: "%{count} hours"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveSupport::Duration calculates its value using the following constants and algorithm (I have added the explanation on what it's doing below but here is a [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f33d52c95217212cbacc8d5e44b5a8e3cdc6f5b3/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L183) to the source). As you can see below, the `SECONDS_PER_YEAR` constant is the **average number of seconds in the gregorian calendar** (which is then used to define `SECONDS_PER_MONTH`). It is because of this, "average definition" of SECONDS_PER_YEAR and SECONDS_PER_MONTH that you are getting the unexpected hours, minutes and seconds. It is defined as an average because a month and year is not a standard fixed amount of time.

```
SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60
SECONDS_PER_HOUR   = 3600
SECONDS_PER_DAY    = 86400
SECONDS_PER_WEEK   = 604800
SECONDS_PER_MONTH  = 2629746 # This is 1/12 of a Gregorian year
SECONDS_PER_YEAR   = 31556952 # The length of a Gregorian year = 365.2425 days

# You pass ActiveSupport::Duration the number of seconds (b-a) = 9255600.0 seconds

remainder_seconds = 9255600.0

# Figure out how many years fit into the seconds using integer division.
years = (remainder_seconds/SECONDS_PER_YEAR).to_i # => 0
# Subtract the amount of years from the remaining_seconds
remainder_seconds -= years * SECONDS_PER_YEAR # => 9255600.0

months = (remainder_seconds/SECONDS_PER_MONTH).to_i # => 3
remainder_seconds -= months * SECONDS_PER_MONTH # => 1366362.0

weeks = (remainder_seconds/SECONDS_PER_WEEK).to_i # => 2
remainder_seconds -= weeks * SECONDS_PER_WEEK # => 156762.0

days = (remainder_seconds/SECONDS_PER_DAY).to_i # => 1
remainder_seconds -= days * SECONDS_PER_DAY # => 70362.0   

hours = (remainder_seconds/SECONDS_PER_HOUR).to_i # => 19
remainder_seconds -= hours * SECONDS_PER_HOUR # => 1962.0

minutes = (remainder_seconds/SECONDS_PER_MINUTE).to_i # => 32
remainder_seconds -= minutes * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE # => 42

seconds = remainder_seconds # => 42

puts "#{years} years, #{months} months, #{weeks} weeks, #{days} days, #{hours} hours, #{minutes} minutes, #{seconds} seconds"
# 0 years, 3 months, 2 weeks, 1 days, 19 hours, 32 minutes, 42.0 seconds
```

To avoid the issue you are having, I would suggest to just represent the time in week, days, hours, minutes and seconds (basically anything excluding month & year).

The number of seconds in a month is complicated if you don't use an average since you will need to account for 28, 29, 30 and 31 days for each separate month. Similarly, for the year, you will need to account for leap/non-leap if you don't use the average.

I am not sure of any gems around which do this for you, however I can provide a function which can help you calculate the duration in days, hours, minutes and seconds below.

```
def duration_in_whms(seconds)
  parts_and_seconds_in_part = {:weeks => 604800, :days => 86400, :hours => 3600, :minutes => 60}
  result = {}
  remainder = seconds
  parts_and_seconds_in_part.each do |k, v|
    result[k] = (remainder/v).to_i
    remainder -= result[k]*v
  end
  result.merge(seconds: remainder)
end

duration_in_whms(9255600) => # {:weeks=>15, :days=>2, :hours=>3, :minutes=>0, :seconds=>0.0}
```